# F# partially implemented interface in abstract class

Tags: interface, f#, abstract-class

I am trying to write an abstract class that partially implements an interface. I also want to set defaults for the non-implemented values. It seems that F# may not support that, but it is equally possible that I just can't get the syntax correct.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is where I am at so far:

```
type IDrawable =
    abstract member Position : Vector2
    abstract member ShortSymbol : int
    abstract member ForeColor : string
    abstract member BackColor : string
    abstract member Symbol : char
    abstract member Description : string

[<AbstractClass>]
type DrawableBase(position, shortSymbol, foreColor, backColor) =

    let position : Vector2 = position
    let shortSymbol : int = shortSymbol
    let foreColor : string = foreColor
    let backColor : string = backColor

    interface IDrawable with
        member this.Position = position
        member this.ShortSymbol = shortSymbol
        member this.ForeColor = foreColor
        member this.BackColor = backColor

        default this.Symbol = char this.ShortSymbol
        default this.Description = ""

    new(oldBase: DrawableBase, newPosition) = DrawableBase(newPosition, oldBase.ShortSymbol, oldBase.ForeColor, oldBase.BackColor)
```

This is for a learning project so most of it doesn't really matter - I'm probably do a few other things wrong here as well - feel free to critique.

Comment: So what of this doesn't actually work?

Comment: It's not liking the `default` keyword under the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard about partial interface implementation, even though I have done some OOP work in F# with type inheritance and interfaces. You could achieve the same result with virtual member at the base class:

```
type IDrawable =
    abstract member Position : Vector2
    abstract member ShortSymbol : int
    abstract member ForeColor : string
    abstract member BackColor : string
    abstract member Symbol : char
    abstract member Description : string

[<AbstractClass>]
type DrawableBase(position, shortSymbol, foreColor, backColor) =

    let position : Vector2 = position
    let shortSymbol : int = shortSymbol
    let foreColor : string = foreColor
    let backColor : string = backColor

    abstract member Symbol : char
    default this.Symbol = char shortSymbol
    abstract member Description : string
    default this.Description = ""

    interface IDrawable with
        member this.Position = position
        member this.ShortSymbol = shortSymbol
        member this.ForeColor = foreColor
        member this.BackColor = backColor

        member this.Symbol = this.Symbol
        member this.Description = this.Description
```

Because interfaces in F# are explicit, I prefer to implement all interface members as a call to the corresponding type members. E.g. in the previous example  the constructor complains that oldBase doesn't have members other than the two virtual ones that I have added:

```
new(oldBase: DrawableBase, newPosition) = DrawableBase(newPosition, oldBase.ShortSymbol, oldBase.ForeColor, oldBase.BackColor)
```

One solution is to change the type of `oldBase` to `IDrawable`:

```
new(oldBase: IDrawable, newPosition) = DrawableBase(newPosition, oldBase.ShortSymbol, oldBase.ForeColor, oldBase.BackColor)
```

Another solution is to add all methods to the type itself. That is more convenient because it allows to avoid explicit casting in many places and work with classes in C# way (where interfaces are implemented implicitly) without annoying `:>` in every place where one needs to call interface members:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type DrawableBase(position, shortSymbol, foreColor, backColor) =

    let position : Vector2 = position
    let shortSymbol : int = shortSymbol
    let foreColor : string = foreColor
    let backColor : string = backColor

    member this.Position = position
    member this.ShortSymbol = shortSymbol
    member this.ForeColor = foreColor
    member this.BackColor = backColor

    abstract member Symbol : char
    default this.Symbol = char shortSymbol
    abstract member Description : string
    default this.Description = ""

    interface IDrawable with
        member this.Position = this.Position
        member this.ShortSymbol = this.ShortSymbol
        member this.ForeColor = this.ForeColor
        member this.BackColor = this.BackColor

        member this.Symbol = this.Symbol
        member this.Description = this.Description

    new(oldBase: DrawableBase, newPosition) = DrawableBase(newPosition, oldBase.ShortSymbol, oldBase.ForeColor, oldBase.BackColor)
```

Note that in some rare cases you would want to implement interface not as a call to a type member, but directly as a call to a field or a private method (i.e. duplicate some code and have it as `member this.Position = position` inside interface as in the type member). This is because for type hierarchies, virtual methods and interfaces inlining at JIT level doesn't always work as with simple classes, so calling `member this.Position = this.Position` incurs an additional virtual call overhead. But this only matters when you need to *nano*optimize, e.g. increase performance from 100 Mops to 150 Mops of a simple method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page for F# interfaces on MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233207.aspx

`default` is never valid for an interface implementation in a class.

However, again from the docs

> However, you can provide a default implementation by also including a
>   separate definition of the member as a method together with the
>   default keyword